# Filter objects with multiple ManyToMany results

Tags: python, django

I have a `Message` model:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    message_from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(class)s_message_form")
    message_to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(class)s_message_to")
    message = models.TextField()
    files = models.ForeignKey(File, null=True, blank=True)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

and an associated view:

```
def view_messages(request):
    messages = Message.objects.filter(message_to=request.user)
    return render(request, 'templates/messages.html', {'messages': messages})
```

Suppose multiple users have messaged a receiver multiple times and this query returns multiple objects. I want to return one object per sender so I can then create a link to a single user's messages. Do I pass something to the `message_from` parameter to ensure I can one object per user back?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually extract `message_from` from the messages and return them instead of returning `messages`.

```
messages = Message.objects.filter(message_to=request.user)
sender_ids = messages.values_list('message_from', flat=True).distinct()
senders = User.objects.filter(id__in=sender_ids)
return render(request, 'templates/messages.html', {'senders': senders})
```

Then in your `messages.html`(I think it's better to call it `senders.html` because you want to click on each sender and check their messages sent) you list all the senders who sent messages to current user, then make them clickable and redirect to a list of messages that that sender has sent to current user.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PostgreSQL as RDBMS, you could use `.disting(*fields)` method.

And your query will be something like this -

`messages = Message.objects.filter(message_to=request.user).distinct('message_from')`

This method is supported only by PostgreSQL (check django docs). In that way you can easily retrieve unread messages or last messages.

But if you want to retrieve users:

`users = User.objects.filter(message_set__message_from=request.user).distinct()`

This method will perform a join, in opposite a subquery from response suggested by @shang-wang .

Comment: This works well as I am using PostgreSQL. Would it be possible to select the last record that appears I.E. the most recent for a user?

Comment: Sure, just order by date descending. But you MUST include date field into distinct clause.

Comment: I have `messages = Message.objects.filter(message_to=request.user).distinct('message_from', 'time_date').order_by(
        '-time_date')` but this returns two different messages from the same user. Should I call distinct twice, separately?

Comment: Oh, sorry, my bad. Don't include `time_date` in distinct clause.

Comment: This causes a `ProgrammingError` when I take it out of the distinct clause.